# Rotating UIButton for 180 degrees and rotating it back

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, rotation

I have `UIButton`, that i wish to rotate in one direction for 180 degrees, and back also for 180 degrees. I have been doing animations for a while using `CABasicAnimation`, but this time i wanted to do it with transforms. Here is the code that i have written:

```
- (IBAction)blurAction:(id)sender {
    if (self.blurActive) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
            self.blurView.alpha = 0;
            self.blurButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            self.blurActive = NO;
        }];
    }
    else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
            self.blurView.alpha = 1;
            self.blurButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            self.blurActive = YES;
        }];
    }
}
```

It works the first time, but second time i press the button, nothing happens. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`M_PI` and `-M_PI` will have the same visual effect

The turning back to it's original position should be

```
self.blurButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
```

--EDIT--

To animate the counter clockwise rotation, you can use `-2*M_PI`

```
self.blurButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-2*M_PI);
```

Comment: Not really, if i put 0, it will make another rotation for 180 degrees in the same direction, which will be original position, but it would be like turning button for 360 degrees clockwise. On the other hand i want rotation for 180 degrees clockwise and then 180 degrees counter clockwise

Comment: For the counter clockwise rotation, you can use `-2*M_PI`

Comment: Not sure then, just tested here, and it's working fine

Comment: My bad on the last one, i didn't commit the code. Put this answer in the comment so i can accept it.

Answer (score 19):

The easiest way to achieve this effect is just to rotate a tiny, tiny amount less than 180°:

```
- (IBAction)toggle:(UIButton *)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        if (CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform(sender.transform, CGAffineTransformIdentity)) {
            sender.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.999);
        } else {
            sender.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }
    }];
}
```

Result:

[image: demo of rotating]

Comment: I like your approach. Here is the Swift 3 code:

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            if self.transform == CGAffineTransform.identity {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * .pi) / 180.0)
            } else {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }
        })

Answer (score 14):

Here is the **Swift3** code for @rob mayoff solution.

```
   @IBAction func fooButton(_ sender: Any) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration:0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
            if sender.transform == .identity {
                sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 0.999))
            } else {
                sender.transform = .identity
            }
        })
    }
```

**Swift4**

`M_PI` is deprecated and replaced with `Double.pi`

```
@IBAction func fooButton(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration:0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        if sender.transform == .identity {
            sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 0.999))
        } else {
            sender.transform = .identity
        }
    })
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Turning UIButton 180º

```
UIButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
```

Turning UIButton 0º or back again

```
UIButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)
```

Example to turn animate

```
if cardViewModel.getBottomMenuVisibility() {
            [UIView .transition(
                with: bottomMenuView,
                duration: 0.3,
                options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                animations: {
                    // Turn UIButton upside down
                    self.bottomMenu.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
            },
                completion: nil)]
    }
    else {
        [UIView .transition(
            with: bottomMenuView,
            duration: 0.3,
            options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
            animations: {
                // Turn UIButton back to normal
                self.bottomMenu.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)
        },
            completion: nil)]
    }
```

You can check on my code this example : 
https://github.com/issuran/Scrum-Geek-Poker/blob/0d032a4b4edcf75cebae1524131f4fe6be3a5edf/Scrum%20Geek%20Poker/Features/CardCollection/View/MainScreenViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

To 'unrotate' the view set the transform to the constant CGAffineTransformIdentity  , which is a transform of zero.  This is the beauty of working with transforms, you don't need to calculate the way back, just undo what you already did.

Comment: UIButton still rotates in the same direction, so it's like 2 180 degrees rotations in same direction

Answer (score 0):

You can not actually achieve this with transforms as transforms holds only information about end state. They do not tell us which direction we should use to make e.g. the rotation.

The best option to achieve 180 degrees forth and back rotation behaviour is to use `CABasicAnimation`.

Here's the example:

```
func rotateImage(forward: Bool) {
    let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    rotationAnimation.fromValue = forward ? 0.0 : CGFloat.pi
    rotationAnimation.toValue = forward ? CGFloat.pi : 0.0
    rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    rotationAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    rotationAnimation.duration = 0.5

    handleImageView.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4+**

```
@IBAction private func maximizeButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            sender.transform = sender.transform == .identity ? CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 0.999)) : .identity
        })
    }
```